# stability of scipy.sparse.linalg.arpack.eigsh for eigen-decomposition of positive semi-definite sparse matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, eigenvalue, arpack

I'm working on a variation of spectral clustering algorithm which performs standard spectral embedding on updated similarity matrix `W` for `n_iters` times, so I have to check the PSD of normalized laplacian matrix `L_rw` generated by updated `W` each iteration before eigen-decomposition. **The problem is that even though the initialized `L_rw` is always PSD theoretically, `arpack` sometimes yield negative eigenvalues(sometimes not always) for it. In a word, `arpack` won't always guarantee non-negative eigenvalues for a semi-definite symmetric matrix.** Below is sample code to illustrate the problem I encountered.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp
from sklearn.utils.extmath import safe_sparse_dot
from scipy.sparse.linalg import arpack
def my_laplacian(W):
    """ Generate normed laplacian matrix L_rw for similarity matrix W 
        (L_rw is according to the definition in `A Tutorial on Spectral 
        Clustering` by Von Luxburg, 2007)
    """
    D = gen_D(W)
    if not np.all(D != 0):
        raise ValueError('W exists all-zero row')
    L_rw = normalize_L(W, D)
    if not isPSD(L_rw):
        raise ValueError('L_rw isn\'t PSD')
    return L_rw
def gen_D(W):
    if sp.issparse(W):
        return np.asarray(W.sum(axis = 0)).squeeze()
    else:
        return W.sum(axis = 0)
def normalize_L(W, D):
    """ Normalize laplacian L with formula L_rw = I - D ^ (-1) * W
    """
    tmp = np.reciprocal(D)
    if sp.issparse(W):
        return sp.eye(W.shape[0], format = 'csr') - safe_sparse_dot(sp.diags(tmp, 0).tocsr(), W)
    else:
        return np.fill_diagonal(-W, 1 - np.einsum('i,i->i', tmp, W.diagonal()))
def isPSD(L, tol = 1e-10):
    """ Check wheter L is positive semi-definite
    """
    vals_large, vecs_large = arpack.eigsh(L, k = 10, which = 'LM', maxiter = 6000)
    vals_small, vecs_small = arpack.eigsh(L, k = 10, sigma = 0, which = 'LM', maxiter = 6000)
    return np.all(vals_small > - tol) and np.all(vals_large > -tol)
```

When I run it:

```
In [2]: X = np.random.random_integers(0, 500, size = (500, 1200))
In [3]: from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import *
In [4]: additive_chi2_kernel(X)
Out[4]: 
array([[     -0.        , -108450.9702963 , -110301.71485863, ...,
        -114578.16996935, -106849.35599894, -102370.37161802],
       [-108450.9702963 ,      -0.        , -109129.14648767, ...,
        -112274.78420127, -107293.6284921 , -103749.55524937],
       [-110301.71485863, -109129.14648767,      -0.        , ...,
       -109282.25057724,  -99851.02992075, -103023.45281752],
       ..., 
       [-114578.16996935, -112274.78420127, -109282.25057724, ...,
         -0.        , -110133.11568012, -111218.58079982],
       [-106849.35599894, -107293.6284921 ,  -99851.02992075, ...,
        -110133.11568012,      -0.        , -102516.65009177],
       [-102370.37161802, -103749.55524937, -103023.45281752, ...,
        -111218.58079982, -102516.65009177,      -0.        ]])
In [5]: W = np.exp(-_ * (1. / X.shape[1]))
In [6]: W = sp.coo_matrix(W).tocsr()
In [7]: my_laplacian(W)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-9b100976a310> in <module>()
----> 1 my_laplacian(W)

<ipython-input-1-dbf198146761> in my_laplacian(W)
     16     L_rw = normalize_L(W, D)
     17     if not isPSD(L_rw):
---> 18         raise ValueError('L_rw isn\'t PSD')
     19     return L_rw

ValueError: L_rw isn't PSD
```

Then I `pdb.run('L_rw = my_laplacian(W)')`, but it got no `ValueError`

```
(Pdb) n
> <ipython-input-1-dbf198146761>(17)my_laplacian()
-> if not isPSD(L_rw):
(Pdb) L_rw
<500x500 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 250000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
(Pdb) n
> <ipython-input-1-dbf198146761>(19)my_laplacian()
-> return L_rw
```

I ran it again:

```
In [9]: my_laplacian(W)
Out[9]: 
<500x500 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 250000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [10]: my_laplacian(W)
Out[10]: 
<500x500 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 250000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [11]: my_laplacian(W)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9b100976a310> in <module>()
----> 1 my_laplacian(W)

<ipython-input-1-dbf198146761> in my_laplacian(W)
     16     L_rw = normalize_L(W, D)
     17     if not isPSD(L_rw):
---> 18         raise ValueError('L_rw isn\'t PSD')
     19     return L_rw
```

It seems like `arpack` not very stable? Or I mistake something? Is there anyone to shed some light?